# Evitar patrón visible en generación de random

Tags: c#, windows-forms, random

Estoy dibujando unos cuadrados en un `canvas` (`PictureBox`) esos cuadros han de situarse de manera aleatoria, el primer problema que tenia con la generación era que los valores generados eran todos los mismos con este código;

```
    public void colocarComidaToda(int ancho, int alto, int cantidad)
    {
        int[] equis = new int[cantidad];
        int[] ies= new int[cantidad];

        for (int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
        {

        int x = generar(ancho);
        int y = generar(alto);
        equis[i] = x;
        ies[i] = y;

        }            

        Clients.All.colocarComidaToda(equis, ies);
    }


    //Genera un numero aleatorio entre 0 y el parametro
    private int generar(int n)
    {
        random = new Random();
        int num = random.Next(0, n) * 10;
        return num;
    }
```

Tras una breve investigación descubrí que la generación del `random` tiene en cuenta la hora del sistema, entonces lo solucioné añadiendo `Thread.Sleep(10);` tras cada generación de la x e y en el método `colocarComidaToda`.

El problema que tengo ahora es que la generación de las posiciones sigue un mismo patrón visible similar siempre a este ;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo generar estas posiciones de manera aleatoria sin que se genere ese patrón diagonal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estas inicializando la semilla cada vez que llamas a la funcion **generar**, esto lo puedes resolver declarando el objeto **Random** de forma estática, algo asi:

```
private static random = new Random();
private int generar(int n)
{
    int num = random.Next(0, n) * 10;
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, lo solucioné de esta manera    `private static readonly Random getrandom = new Random();

        public static int GetRandomNumber(int max)
        {
            lock (getrandom) // synchronize
            {
                return getrandom.Next(0, max) * 10;
            }
        }`